Multidimensional person
Rabbeinu Ari writes :

כי כמו שמשה רבינו ע"ה הוא בבחי' הדעת העליון דז"א מצד אבא כן בלעם היה הרע שבמשה והיה כנגדו בדעת
...because, just as Moshe, our Rabbi A'H represents the aspect of the
Da'at Eliyon of Zeir Anpin, from the side of Abba
[Kabbalistic/Chassidic terminology/metaphors], so too was Bilam, the
evil/negativity of/in Moshe, corresponding to him in Da'at.

(Shaar haHakdamot, Seven Kings of Edom 1)
The Ari says that the Bilam is the "evil in Moses" and at the same time he is a process in the shvirat haKelim which happened before there was Adam and at the same time he is the evil prophet who lived at the time of Moses.
My question is: Can someone explain how one person is at the same time a part of another and simultaniously a concept and if there are more cases of a person being "multidemensional" ?

Obviously, I can't explain what this all means, but there are subject headers:

A person can be a "concept" because our souls are rooted in the higher realms, which also correspond to concepts. A soul being rooted in "da'at elyon" means that that soul's way of operating, and viewing the world, is rooted in the higher da'at that analyses good and evil and chooses the good, whereas a soul rooted in the lower da'at will merely be the world's expert at mixing good and evil (See Podoh Beshalom 5672).
A person being part of another is a basic concept that we are all part of Adam. His soul is composed of 10 sefirot, and "broke" into many pieces. If you realise that the sefirot are contained within eachother fractally, you can see how the 10 can become millions - there is a soul that is Chesed within Chesed within Gevura within Tiferet within Da'at, and depending exactly on this make up/spiritual anatomy, he will see operate and see things in his unique way. Someone higher than him on the chain will be able to see things his way too, and become his teacher, and acts as his root (See Shaar Hagilgulim)

